# Upload file excel and read with JAX-RS 2.0 in java

Tags: java, excel, jax-rs

I have upload file excel function that run normally in Websphere server 8.5 with JAX-RS 1.1. But when I update to Websphere 9.0 using JAX_RS 2.0, I cannot use @FormParam to upload file, I tried using @MultiPart to replace but it can read .csv file right only, with .xls and .xlsx file it create wrong temp file, so HSSFWorkbook of Apache Poi cannot read inputstream of file normally.
This is my code:

Controller:

```
@POST
    @Path("class/import")
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @RolesAllowed(Role.TRAINING_ADMIN)
    public Response importClass(@FormParam("file") File file) {

        InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);
        HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(is);
        if (checkTokenAndRole(new int[] {1, 11}).getStatus() != Response.Status.OK.getStatusCode()) {           
            return LoginError(checkToken().getStatus());                
        } else {
            String token = request.getHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION);
            String fileExtension = request.getHeader("FileExtension");
            return ClassService.getInstance().importClass(file, fileExtension,
                    token);
        }
    }
```

HTML and Js file:

```
<form data-bind="submit: cancel">
    <div class="modal-dialog dialog-class">
        <div class="modal-content dialog-class">
            <div class="modal-header layout-dialog-header">
                <div class="layout-float-left dialog-close-icon">
                    <span class="glyphicon doc-icon-close-nav" data-bind="click: cancel"></span>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <h5 data-bind="text: title" data-i18n="modules.class.uploadSchedule"></h5>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class=" docs-margin-top-s">
                    <div>
                        <div class="form-group marginBot35">
                            <div class="class-browse">
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <div>
                                        <label class="label-md search-class-header" for="">
                                        <span class="search-class-header" data-i18n="modules.class.uploadClasslist" data-bind="text: listClass"></span>
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div id="" class="col-md-8 control-upload no-padding-left">
                                        <input readonly="true" tabindex="3" class="col-md-12" id='uploadFile' type="text" name=""  style="min-height: 40px" data-bind="value: name, attr: {'title': name()}"/>
                                    </div>
                                    <div clas="col-md-4">
                                        <label for="input-file-upload" tabindex="3" class="pull-right btn btn-secondary-aia btn-cancel font-size20" data-dismiss="modal"
                                        data-i18n="buttons.buttonBrowse" >Browse
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="class-center-align">
                                    <label class="label-md search-class-header " for="">
                                        <span class="search-class-header" data-i18n="modules.class.downloadThe">Download the</span>
<!--                                         <a class="class-highlight" tabindex="3" data-i18n="modules.class.trainingSchedule" data-bind="attr: {href: template}, text: textTemplate" download>Training Schedule Template</a> -->
                                            <a class="class-highlight" tabindex="3" data-i18n="modules.class.trainingSchedule" data-bind="click: $root.download, text: textTemplate" >Training Schedule Template</a>
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12 footer-class" style="padding-bottom:40px">
                <button tabindex="3" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary-aia btn-cancel font-size20" data-dismiss="modal" data-i18n="buttons.buttonCancel" data-bind="click: cancel"></button>
                <button tabindex="3" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary-aia btn-save font-size20 " style=" cursor: pointer; word-spacing: normal !important" data-bind="click: upload, disable: !readyUpload(),text: buttonUpload" data-dismiss="modal" data-i18n="buttons.buttonUploadSchedule"></button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>


<form id="form-input-file-upload" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" style="display:none">
    <input id="input-file-upload" type="file" style="" name="file" size="45" accept=".xls,.xlsx" style="display:none" data-bind="attr: {accept: acceptedFiles},event: {change: addFile}" >
</form>
```

```
define([
    'durandal/app',
    'durandal/events',
    'plugins/dialog',
    'plugins/http',
    'knockout',
    'jquery',
    'config',
    'services/utils',
    'i18next',
    'services/document'
], function (app, Events, dialog, http, ko, $, Config, Utils, i18next, DocumentService) {
    'use strict';

            return function UploadBulkSchedule(mode) {
        var self = this;
        Events.includeIn(self);
        if(mode === 1){
            self.title = ko.observable( i18next.t("modules.bulkAttendee.title") ?  i18next.t("modules.bulkAttendee.title") :  "");
            self.listClass = ko.observable( i18next.t("modules.bulkAttendee.listClass") ?  i18next.t("modules.bulkAttendee.listClass") : "");
            self.textTemplate = ko.observable( i18next.t("modules.bulkAttendee.template") ?  i18next.t("modules.bulkAttendee.template") : "");
            self.buttonUpload = ko.observable( i18next.t("modules.bulkAttendee.buttonUpload") ?  i18next.t("modules.bulkAttendee.buttonUpload") : "");
        }else{
            self.title = ko.observable( i18next.t("modules.class.uploadSchedule") ?  i18next.t("modules.class.uploadSchedule") :  "");
            self.listClass = ko.observable( i18next.t("modules.class.uploadClasslist") ?  i18next.t("modules.class.uploadClasslist") : "");
            self.textTemplate = ko.observable( i18next.t("modules.class.trainingSchedule") ?  i18next.t("modules.class.trainingSchedule") :  "");
            self.buttonUpload = ko.observable( i18next.t("buttons.buttonUploadSchedule") ?  i18next.t("buttons.buttonUploadSchedule") : "");
        }
        self.name = ko.observable();


        var acceptedFileArr = [
                            'application/vnd.ms-excel',
                            'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet',
                            'application/csv',
                            '.xls','.xlsx', '.csv'];
        var acceptedExtension = ['xls', 'xlsx', 'csv'];
        self.mode = mode;
        self.acceptedFiles = ko.observable(acceptedFileArr.join(','));
        self.readyUpload = ko.computed(function(){
            return self.name() ? true : false;
        });
        var maxSize = 5242880;

        self.template = (self.mode === 1) ? Config.getBackendBaseUrl('/temp/excel/AttendanceImportTemplate/AttendeeListTemplate.xls') :Config.getBackendBaseUrl('/temp/excel/ClassImportTemplate/ClassImportTemplate.zip');
        self.templateCSV = Config.getBackendBaseUrl('/temp/excel/ClassImportTemplate/ClassImportTemplate.csv');
        var filesArray = [];


        self.cancel = function(){
            dialog.close(self); 
        };


        self.active = function(){

        };

        self.upload = function(data, e){
            e.preventDefault();

            app.showLoading();
            var inputTag = $('#form-input-file-upload :input')[0];
            var fileName = $(inputTag).val().replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '');

            var extension = fileName.split('.').pop();

             var headers = {
                        FileExtension: extension,
                        FileName: encodeURIComponent(fileName),
                        'Authorization':  app.user().get('token'),
                        'isCourseImage': 0
                    };
                    if (self.mode === 1) {

                        self.trigger('uploadSuccess', [ $('#form-input-file-upload :input')[0] ]);

                    } else {
                        Utils
                                .uploadFile(
                                        'class/import',
                                        new FormData(
                                                $('#form-input-file-upload')[0]),
                                        headers)
                                .then(
                                        function() {
                app.hideLoading();
                                        },
                                        function(response) {
                                            var title = i18next
                                                    .t('modules.class.errorTitle');
                var options = [{
                                                text : i18next
                                                        .t('buttons.buttonOk'),
                    value: Config.Events.DialogMessage.OK
                }];
                if(response.status === 200){
                    app.hideLoading();
                } else if(response.status === 500){
                                                var errorMessage = Utils
                                                        .getErrorMessage(response);
                    var errorCode = '';
                    var developerMessage = '';
                    try{
                                                    errorCode = JSON
                                                            .parse(response.responseText).errorCode;
                                                    developerMessage = JSON
                                                            .parse(response.responseText).message;
                    } catch(e){
                    }

                                                if (errorCode === 1007
                                                        && developerMessage) {
                                                    var messageContent = '<br></br><b>'
                                                            + i18next
                                                                    .t(
                                                                            'message.error.importClassSuccess')
                                                                    .format(
                                                                            developerMessage)
                                                            + '</b><br></br>';
                                                    title = i18next
                                                            .t('message.error.importSuccess');
                                                    app
                                                            .showMessageConfirmTitle(
                                                                    messageContent,
                                                                    title,
                                                                    options,
                                                                    false,
                                                                    {
                                                                        class : 'success-class'
                                                                    })
                                                            .then(
                                                                    function() {
                                                                        self
                                                                                .trigger('uploadSuccess');
                                                                        dialog
                                                                                .close(self);
                        });
                    } else if(errorMessage){
                                                    app.showMessageError(
                                                            errorMessage,
                                                            title, options,
                                                            false, null);
                    }
                } else if(response.status === 0) {
                                                var errorMessage = i18next
                                                        .t('message.error.notSaveClassList');
                                                app.showMessageError(
                                                        errorMessage, title,
                                                        options, false, null);

                }
                app.hideLoading();
            });
                    }
        };

        self.browse = function(){
            filesArray = [];
            document.getElementById("uploadFile").click();
        };

        self.addFile = function(data, event){
            var inputFile = document.getElementById("input-file-upload");
            var path = inputFile.value.toString();

            var uploadFile = event.currentTarget;

            var file = uploadFile.files[0];
            var fsize = file.size;

            var name, extension;
            name =  path.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '');
            extension = name.split('.').pop();        


            if( fsize > maxSize){
                self.name('');
                $('#input-file-upload').replaceWith($('#input-file-upload').clone(true));
                showUploadMessageWithData(file);
                $('#input-file-upload')[0].value = '';
            } else if(acceptedExtension.indexOf(extension.toLowerCase()) < 0){
                self.name('');
                $('#input-file-upload').replaceWith($('#input-file-upload').clone(true));  
                var messageContent = '<br/><b>'+i18next.t('modules.class.wrongFileExtension')+' </b><br/>';
                var options = [{
                    text: i18next.t('buttons.buttonClose'),
                    value: Config.Constants.MessageBox.DialogResult.BUTTON_INDEX_0
                }];
                var title = i18next.t('modules.class.errorTitle');
                app.showMessageError(messageContent, title, options, false, null);
                $('#input-file-upload')[0].value = '';
            } else {
                self.name(name);
            }
        };

        function showUploadMessageWithData (file) {
            var messageContent = '<p style="white-space: pre-wrap">'+i18next.t('modules.course.editPage.fileName')+': ' + file.name + '</p>';
            messageContent += '</br><p><b>'+i18next.t('modules.course.editPage.warnUploadFile')+' </b></p>';            messageContent += '<p><b>'+i18next.t('modules.course.editPage.requireUploadFile')+ ' </b></p>';
            var options = [{
                text: i18next.t('buttons.buttonOk'),
                value: Config.Constants.MessageBox.DialogResult.BUTTON_INDEX_0
            }];
            var title = i18next.t('modules.class.errorTitle');
            return app.showMessageError(messageContent, title, options, false, {class: 'confirm-class'}).then(function () {
            });
        }

      //download Material
        self.download = function(fileDownload){
            app.showLoading();
            DocumentService.downloadTemplate(fileDownload.template).then(function (response) {
                app.hideLoading();
                var extension = fileDownload.template.split('.').pop();
                var ctType = '';
                switch(extension) {
                case 'jpg':
                case 'jpeg':
                    ctType = 'image/jpeg';
                    break;
                case 'png':
                    ctType = 'image/png';
                    break;
                case 'doc':
                    ctType = 'application/msword';
                    break;
                case 'docx':
                    ctType = 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document';
                    break;
                case 'xls':
                    ctType = 'application/vnd.ms-excel';
                    break;
                case 'xlsx':
                    ctType = 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet';
                    break;
                case 'ppt':
                    ctType = 'application/vnd.ms-powerpoint';
                    break;
                case 'pptx':
                    ctType = 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation';
                    break;
                case 'pdf':
                    ctType = 'application/pdf';
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }                
                var byteArray = new Uint8Array(response.data);
                var a = window.document.createElement('a');
                a.setAttribute("id", "tmpHref");
                a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([byteArray], { type: ctType }));
                a.download = fileDownload.template.split("/")[fileDownload.template.split("/").length - 1];
                // Append anchor to body.
                document.body.appendChild(a);
                a.click();
                // Remove anchor from body
                document.body.removeChild(a);
            }, function (response) {
                app.hideLoading();
                Utils.downloadMaterial(response);
            });
        };

    };
});
```

Anyone can help me give a solution?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had the solution. I change use IMultipartBody instead using @FormParam,changing ImultipartBody to byte array and use it instead a file.